# iOS8 - Presenting a modal view removes sub view

Tags: ios, uiview, ios8, modalviewcontroller

I am updating our app to be compiled with xcode6/iOS8.

One issue I am running into is that when a modal view is presented. the underlying subview is removed.  It is completely blacked out.. until the modal view is dismissed.. then it re-appears.

Has anyone run into this with iOS8?  The same code has worked since iOS4.

Code:

```
    PigDetailViewController *pigDetailViewController = [[PigDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PigDetailViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    self.navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;


    [self presentViewController:pigDetailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 8 they've added a new presentation style that behaves like UIModalPresentationCurrentContext in the circumstance you've described, it's UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext. The catch here is that unlike with UIModalPresentationCurrentContext, you want to set the view controller to be PRESENTED with this presentation style, like so:

```
PigDetailViewController *pigDetailViewController = [[PigDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PigDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
pigDetailViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
self.navigationController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
[self presentViewController:pigDetailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Note that to support iOS 7 and below you'll likely need to check the OS version and decide how to present the view controller based on that.

edit: I'd like to add one more note to this. In iOS7 with UIModalPresentationCurrentContext, when the presented VC was dismissed, the underlying VC had its viewDidAppear method called. In iOS8 with UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext, I've found the underlying VC does not have its viewDidAppear method called when the VC presented over top of it is dismissed.

Comment: I concur with Roger, this is the correct answer and should be marked as such.

Comment: Any idea make the underlying vc viewDidAppear be called?

Answer (score 0):

Adding a point to BrennanR's answer.. even viewWillAppear doesn't call when the VC presented over top of it is dismissed.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are misunderstanding how a modal view **controller** works.

When you present a view controller modally it will control the entire screen. It has an opaque background (normally black) and then draws its view on top of that.

So, if you set the `view.backgroundColor` to yellow (for example) it will have a yellow background. If you set it to clear then it will show through to the black background.

What I think you want is for the other view to "show through" so it looks like the modal view is sitting on top of it.

The best way I have found of doing this is to use this method...

```
// in the view controller that is presenting the modal VC
modalVC = // the modal VC that you will be presenting

UIView *snapshotView = [self.view snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:NO];
[modalVC.view insertSubView:snapshotView atIndex:0];

// present the modal VC
```

This will take a "screenshot" of the current view hierarchy and then place that snapshot underneath everything in the modal VC.

That way your black screen will be replaced by a screenshot of the previous view controller.

Comment: Thank you.  My concern id that this has worked fine for over 2 years.. it is just with iOS8 that this started to happen.  My modal view is smaller than the underlying view it pops up over.. in the past the underlying view was still visible (around the sides of the modally presented view).

Comment: Starting in iOS 7, you can use the `UIModalPresentationCustom` along with a custom transitioningDelegate to inset the presentedViewController as a custom modal... Then in iOS 8, you can go one step further and use a custom `UIPresentationController` to give you better control over any "accessory views" (i.e dimming views) that you want to also present as well

Comment: @Fogmeister I think mtg is right the way he is describing this. I have the same issue and checked it with Reaveal. Indeed the underlying view hierarchy is removed.

Comment: @brainray that is the correct behaviour though. The bit he is not correct about is that this ever didn't happen. I don't think that has ever been the case.

Comment: This statement: "When you present a view controller modally it will control the entire screen. It has an opaque background (normally black) and then draws its view on top of that." is 100% wrong.

Comment: ...The other part of the answer is overkill. Brennan's answer is a lot cleaner.